# reflection. get value of inherited overraided property

Tags: c#, reflection, asp.net-core

i have 2 classes like this.

```
public class A
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public abstract string Type { get; }
}
public class B
{
    public override string Type => "value";
}
```

i need to find the value of property Type in class B. 
using NET core i try to get the value in this way:

```
var value = typeof(B).GetProperty("Type").GetValue(typeof(B));
```

i get this exception:

Object does not match target type.

even passing typeof(A) in GetValue() i keep getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument to `GetValue` doesn't take a `Type` instance, it needs to accept an instance of the type of the object the member is defined on.  So here you need to pass *an instance of a `B` object*, and not a `Type` object that represents the `B` type.